# How to play with ParaViewWeb

Tags: vtk, paraview

I'm in a project which needs use ParaViewWeb. But I can't find any good tutorial about it. Anyone has any recommendation? Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out: http://www.paraview.org/ParaView3/Doc/Nightly/www/js-doc/index.html#!/guide

The documentation is being updated to expect more details to appear as time progresses.